# WPF datatrigger not firing

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I'm trying to change the background colour of a text box in WPF based on its content.

Using breakpoints, I see my ValueConverter gets constructed, but neither Convert nor ConvertBack methods ever get called, and so the styling doesn't work.

The 'LightBlue' style in the XAML does work at startup.

I tried to use Snoop but I don't know what I'm looking for.

XAML...

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ThreadCreationLimitChanged x:Key="ThreadCreationLimitChanged"></local:ThreadCreationLimitChanged>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Content="New Thread Limit"></Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10, 5, 10, 0" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=ManagerConfig.ThreadCreationLimit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource ThreadCreationLimitChanged}}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

ValueConverter...

```
public class ThreadCreationLimitChanged : IValueConverter
{
    public ThreadCreationLimitChanged()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString() == "120";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

A bit of class ManagerConfig... (NotifyPropertyChanged implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
class ManagerConfig : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private uint _ThreadCreationLimit;

    public uint ThreadCreationLimit
    {
        get { return _ThreadCreationLimit; }
        set
        {
            _ThreadCreationLimit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ThreadCreationLimit");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the `ManagerConfig` property also notify on property changed? Using Snoop: look for the datacontext first. If it contains what you expect, then move on to the bindings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this `{Binding Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource ThreadCreationLimitChanged}}` to `{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} ,Converter={StaticResource ThreadCreationLimitChanged}}`

Comment: Thanks for answer!  Everything works now.  Note that you have a typo - RelativeSourcer should be RelativeSource

Comment: this got me out of some troubles, but how come this works ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a computed property on `ManagerConfig` which reports a status for the change of the `ThreadCreationLimit`? That way one doesn't need a converter. Code such as this:

```
public bool IsOverLimit { get { return ThreadCreationLimit > 120 } }

 public uint ThreadCreationLimit
    {
        get { return _ThreadCreationLimit; }
        set
        {
            _ThreadCreationLimit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ThreadCreationLimit");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsOverLimit");
        }
    }
```

Then bind the data trigger to `IsOverLimit` which will have a change notification sent everytime `ThreadCreationLimit` is set/changed.

An added plus is that the business logic is on the intended class and not a converter.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are having Binding errors.Have checked like below,

1) Accessing TextBox directly for Value,

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:ThreadCreationLimitChanged x:Key="ThreadCreationLimitChanged"></local:ThreadCreationLimitChanged>
</Grid.Resources>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Content="New Thread Limit"></Label>
<TextBox x:Name="tBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10, 5, 10, 0" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=ManagerConfig.ThreadCreationLimit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=tBox,Converter={StaticResource ThreadCreationLimitChanged}}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

2) Accesing proper Model values,

```
 <Grid.Resources>
    <local:ThreadCreationLimitChanged x:Key="ThreadCreationLimitChanged"></local:ThreadCreationLimitChanged>
</Grid.Resources>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Content="New Thread Limit"></Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10, 5, 10, 0" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=ManagerConfig.ThreadCreationLimit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ManagerConfig.ThreadCreationLimit,Converter={StaticResource ThreadCreationLimitChanged}}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```